# Where are the Outlook report files physically kept?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, business-contact-manager

I'd love to edit a specific report by hand but can't figure out where they are located.

I'm using Microsoft Outlook's Business Contact Manager 2010.

Do you know where they are located?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get your hands dirty, try [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) and see what paths it accessed while you report.